# How can I use a for loop in Python to create a string?

Tags: python, numpy, loops

For homework we were given the following problem:

> Use a for loop to create a string called chant with the value "Gimme a 1! Gimme a 2! Gimme a 3!..." all the way up to "Gimme a 5578!"

I tried something like this:

```
numbers=np.arange(1,5579)
for x in numbers:
    message="'Gimme a {}!'".format(x)
    chant="{}".format(message)
print(chant)
```

Which only prints "Gimme a 5578!" That makes sense to me, as that would be the most recent iteration the loop ran through. So I understand why that happened. But I don't know how to make it "save" each iteration of the loop, if that makes sense. I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
numbers=np.arange(1,5579)
for x in numbers:
    message="'Gimme a {}!'".format(x)
    chant=chant+message
print(chant)
```

Which is definitely wrong, but also the closest I've gotten. It printed

```
'Gimme a 5578!''Gimme a 5578!''Gimme a 1!''Gimme a 2!' ... 'Gimme a 5577!''Gimme a 5578!'
```

But I don't really get why it printed that.

Comment: `print ''.join([f"Gimme a {i}!" for i in range(1,5579)]`

Comment: Your last code appears to work fine once you set `chant` before the loop.

Comment: The first one is almost perfect. Look at it for another minute to find the mistake.

Comment: Why are you enclosing `message` in both double and single quotes? You have `"'this'"` instead of `"this"` or `'this'`?

Comment: You really do not need to use numpy. python range will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s=''
for i in range(1,5579):
    s+='Gimme a '+str(i)+'!'
```

Output:

```
print(s)

'Gimme a 1!Gimme a 2!Gimme a 3!Gimme a 4!...Gimme a 5578!'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join and list comprehension to make it shorter:

```
message=''.join(["Gimme a {}!".format(x) for x in range(5579)])
print(message)
#Gimme a 0!Gimme a 1!Gimme a 2!Gimme a 3!Gimme a 4!Gimme a 5!Gimme a 6!Gimme a 7!Gimme a 8!Gimme a 9!...
```

Another way to do with for loop which creates an empty message and then adds each chant to it over a for loop using string formatting:

```
message = ''
for x in range(5579):
    message += "Gimme a {}!".format(x)
print(message)
#Gimme a 0!Gimme a 1!Gimme a 2!Gimme a 3!Gimme a 4!Gimme a 5!Gimme a 6!Gimme a 7!Gimme a 8!Gimme a 9!...
```

Comment: They are asked to use a for loop

Comment: @IoaTzimas I see. Hope this answer helps someone else then. I added a different for loop than your answer as well in case anyone is interested. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It’s need to define chant as 3rd string:

```
import numpy as np
numbers=np.arange(1,5579)
chant='' # define chant
for x in numbers:
    message="'Gimme a {}!'".format(x)
    chant=chant+message
print(chant)
```